# Better way to write multiple if statements in java

Tags: java

Hi so lately I've been doing a lot of java programming and I've been using a lot of if statements. the problem is i have to copy and paste the if statements over a hundred times to check all the senarios. Here is an example:

```
while (i < AreaNumbers.size()) {
        String roomnum = "j" + AreaNumbers.get(i);
        if (roomnum.equals("j100")) {
            if (k == 1) {
                j100.setVisible(true);
                j100.setToolTipText("<html>" + "<br>" + "Room Number: " + AreaNumbers.get(i) + "<br>" + "Incident ID: " + IncidentID.get(i) + "<br>" + " Teacher: " + Teachers.get(i) + "<br>" + " Description: " + Descriptions.get(i) + "</html>");
                k = k + 1;
            } else if (k > 0) {
                j100.setToolTipText(k + " help desk calls, click here for more information");
                k = k + 1;
            }
```

for this example i would copy and paste the `if (roomnum.equals("j100")) {` and everything past it for every label i want to check and compare. Is there anyway i could do this where i could write a statement that goes through this same scenario once and everywhere it sees `j100` it could replace it after each time with a different label, such as j101 j107 an so on. Im sorry if this isnt very clear i just cant think of a better way to word it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have a variable named `j100` and, according to your description, this code will be repeated over a hundred times. Does it mean you plan on having hundred variables like that?

Comment: so you would dynamic variables, like php? `${$name}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use numbered variable names (like `j100`, `j101`, etc.).  Use an array instead, so you can loop over them programatically:

```
SomeType[] j = new SomeType[1000];

for (int z = 0; z < j.length; z++) {
    j[z] = new SomeType();

    j[z].setTooltipText("Hello world");
}
```

Depending on what you need to do, you may want to investigate the more advanced [collections classes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/intro/index.html) instead of simple arrays.

Comment: I hope you never get to room -1

Answer (score 0):

you could use a `Map<String, Runnable>` using the label as the key and to a `Runnable`. Depending on how you write you Runnable subclasses, this could alleviate a lot of redundancy.

```
if( myMap.containsKey( myLabel ) ) {
  myMap.get(myLabel).run();
}
```

Comment: I believe this approach is a bit too advanced for the question.

Comment: What do `Runnable`s have to do with `Thread`s besides the fact that a `Thread` can take a `Runnable` in the ctor? A Runnable is just an interface with a `run` method. Unlike c++ java does not have `operator()` for I used `Runnable`. This is the closest I can get to a functor in java6. You could use `Callable` or even create your own interface if you don't like `Runnable`.

Comment: As far as I understand it, the `Runnable` interface is designed for actions to be executed by a thread (it even says so in the documentation).  It seems a bit perverse to implement this interface just to get a `run()` method, which you could quite easily do with a custom interface (that doesn't lead to confusion about threads!).

Comment: Why introduce a new interface that will almost certainly be exactly the same as Runnable? Runnable is the closest thing java currently has to a no-return lambda/functor. The interface `Runnable` has nothing intrinsically tying it to Thread.

Comment: You could also create your own interface with a go() or do() or execute() method. This way, you would not confuse those who are used to seeing Runnable in threading environments.

Comment: @Kitsune: Because `Runnable` is trivial to re-declare (it contains a single method).  You're right, there's nothing stopping you re-using it, but it would be at the cost of making the intention of your code less than clear.